# Nested arrays in POST in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

ExtJS grid filter plugin passes filter data in the array (via POST) with such fields:

```
filter[0][field] => Id
filter[0][data][value] => 42
filter[0][data][type] => integer
```

What is the simplest way to retrieve all N filter sets in asp.net (mvc2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

essentially you make a object which matches the desired structure and names required

```
class typeA
{ 
  int value;
  string type;
}

class typeB
{
   typeA data; 
}

class typeC
{
  List<typeB> filter
}
```

then use typeC as the input for the for the controler.

Comment: Even though it is not already actual now, I'll check you :-) Thanks for the reply ;-)